# Arraylist android

Tags: java, android

I am making a quiz application and using the `ArrayList` with. I have a problem with the Answers: it is working when I have just one answer, but what can I do if the question has two answers?

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import cn.pedant.SweetAlert.SweetAlertDialog;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView questionLabel, questionCountLabel, scoreLabel;
    EditText answerEdt;
    Button submitButton;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    ArrayList<QuestionModel> questionModelArraylist;


    int currentPosition = 0;
    int numberOfCorrectAnswer = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        questionCountLabel = findViewById(R.id.noQuestion);
        questionLabel = findViewById(R.id.question);
        scoreLabel = findViewById(R.id.score);

        answerEdt = findViewById(R.id.answer);
        submitButton = findViewById(R.id.submit);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress);

        questionModelArraylist = new ArrayList<>();

        setUpQuestion();

        setData();

        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                checkAnswer();
            }
        });

        answerEdt.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
                Log.e("event.getAction()",event.getAction()+"");
                Log.e("event.keyCode()",keyCode+"");
                if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                        (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

                    checkAnswer();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
    public void checkAnswer(){
        String answerString  = answerEdt.getText().toString().trim();




        if(answerString.equalsIgnoreCase(questionModelArraylist.get(currentPosition).getAnswer())){
            numberOfCorrectAnswer ++;



            new SweetAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, SweetAlertDialog.SUCCESS_TYPE)
                    .setTitleText("Sehr gut!")
                    .setContentText("Richtig!")
                    .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog) {
                            currentPosition ++;

                            setData();
                            answerEdt.setText("");
                            sweetAlertDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    })
                    .show();


        }else {

            new SweetAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, SweetAlertDialog.ERROR_TYPE)
                    .setTitleText("Falsch :(")
                    .setContentText("Die Richtige Antwort ist : "+questionModelArraylist.get(currentPosition).getAnswer())
                    .setConfirmText("OK")
                    .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sDialog) {
                            sDialog.dismiss();

                            currentPosition ++;

                            setData();
                            answerEdt.setText("");
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
        }





        int x = ((currentPosition+1) * 100) / questionModelArraylist.size();

        progressBar.setProgress(x);



    }




    public void setUpQuestion(){


        questionModelArraylist.add(new QuestionModel("Write one planet located between Earth and the sun?", " Mercury or Venus"));
    }

    public void setData(){


        if(questionModelArraylist.size()>currentPosition) {

            questionLabel.setText(questionModelArraylist.get(currentPosition).getQuestionString());

            scoreLabel.setText("Ergebnis :" + numberOfCorrectAnswer + "/" + questionModelArraylist.size());
            questionCountLabel.setText("Frage Nummer : " + (currentPosition + 1));


        }else{


            new SweetAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, SweetAlertDialog.SUCCESS_TYPE)
                    .setTitleText("Du bist Fertig :)")
                    .setContentText("dein Ergebnis ist : "+ numberOfCorrectAnswer + "/" + questionModelArraylist.size())
                    .setConfirmText("Wiederholen")
                    .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sDialog) {

                            sDialog.dismissWithAnimation();
                            currentPosition = 0;
                            numberOfCorrectAnswer = 0;
                            progressBar.setProgress(0);
                            setData();
                        }
                    })
                    .setCancelText("schließen")
                    .setCancelClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sDialog) {

                            sDialog.dismissWithAnimation();
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .show();

        }

    }



}
```

Question Class

```
public class QuestionModel {

    public QuestionModel(String questionString, String answer) {
        QuestionString = questionString;
        Answer = answer;
    }

    public String getQuestionString() {
        return QuestionString;
    }

    public void setQuestionString(String questionString) {
        QuestionString = questionString;
    }

    public String getAnswer() {
        return Answer;
    }

    public void setAnswer(String answer) {
        Answer = answer;
    }

    private String QuestionString;
    private String Answer;


}
```

As you can see, I want to make the answer to be `Mercury` or `Venus`, but I can't make it work.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is while creating the object for QuestionModel send the ArrayList
for the answers

```
QuestionModel object=new QuestionModel("Write one planet located between Earth and the sun?", arraylist for answers)
```

when you call getAnswer() method in checkAnswer() method it will give you the ArrayList of answer for that particular question and then you can use

```
 if (answerlist.contains("Mercury") && answerlist.contains("Venus"){
 //insert your logic for correct answer
}
```

then you can match the two or more answer

your model class will be like

```
public class QuestionModel {

private String QuestionString;
private ArrayList<String> Answer;

public QuestionModel(String questionString, ArrayList answer) {
    QuestionString = questionString;
    Answer = answer;
}

public String getQuestionString() {
    return QuestionString;
}

public void setQuestionString(String questionString) {
    QuestionString = questionString;
}

public ArrayList getAnswer() {
    return Answer;
}

public void setAnswer(ArrayList answer) {
    Answer = answer;
}
```

}

Comment: It probably should be `if (answerlist.contains("Mercury") || answerlist.contains("Venus"){... }`.

Comment: thank you for your help...but my Question is: what can i do if i have more than one Question
i mean:

questionModelArraylist.add(new QuestionModel("Write one planet located between Earth and the sun","Venus or Mercury"));

questionModelArraylist.add(new QuestionModel("the 5th planet from the sun","Jupiter"));

questionModelArraylist.add(new QuestionModel("write names of any two oceans","Atlantic Ocean or Arctic Ocean or Indian Ocean or Pacific Ocean orSouthern Ocean"));

Comment: i am not sure what you are asking for you can put full Question again but as far as understand if you have more than one question in arraylist than how can you match the answer??
So as your arraylist is store the object you can store that particular object with the answer in the Hashmap and object address will be the key at the time of matching the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it appears you have an ArrayList of Questions. Each question appears to have a property of answers. My answer is a bit of a shortcut, you are going to want to add the actual String "Venus" to your questions property.

Also I turned your String into a more readable String

The || operator means "or" in Java/Android

String mercuryString= questionModelArraylist.get(currentPosition).getAnswer()

```
if(answerString.equalsIgnoreCase(mercuryString) || 
answerString.equalsIgnoreCase("Venus"){

 numberOfCorrectAnswer ++;
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your help...but my Question is: what can i do if i have more than one Question
i mean:

questionModelArraylist.add(new QuestionModel("Write one planet located between Earth and the sun","Venus or Mercury"));

questionModelArraylist.add(new QuestionModel("the 5th planet from the sun","Jupiter"));

questionModelArraylist.add(new QuestionModel("write names of any two oceans","Atlantic Ocean or Arctic Ocean or Indian Ocean or Pacific Ocean orSouthern Ocean"));